# Are there any advantages to using absolute symlinks over relative ones?

Tags: security, capistrano, symlink, apache-mina

I'm in the process of discussing issues with [`capistrano`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/1187) and [`mina`](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/issues/496). They now create absolute symlinks, pointing to current release of a site.

I see downsides to using absolute symlinks:

1. They doesn't work outside of any sort of chroot.
2. They break if you move directory, containing absolute symlinks.

Are there any reasons to choose absolute symlinks over relative ones?

Comment: Relative links are harder to get right.

Comment: You mean it's easier to make a mistake when creating relative symlink, as opposed to absolute one? Like, make it point to the wrong directory?